# How to rotate a pixel/point around (0, 0) in C?

Tags: c, rotation, linear-algebra

I already have the formula for rotating (px, py) around (ox, oy) by angle theta:

```
p'x = cos(theta) * (px-ox) - sin(theta) * (py-oy) + ox
p'y = sin(theta) * (px-ox) + cos(theta) * (py-oy) + oy
```

But when I set theta to:

```
double theta = 5 * PI / 180;
```

My point stays on the starting point [link: (5, 5)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETcaN.png), whilst when I set theta to:

```
double theta = 6 * PI / 180;
```

It starts rotating like a [link: square](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTQ70.png). I know that's supposed to happen because command prompt is like a huge monitor and there can't be a circle, but how can I make it rotate any point I set it to? For example the 6 * PI / 180 above doesn't work when my dot is [link: (2, 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20whP.png).

EDIT: ox, oy are (0, 0).

Comment: can you add the source code of the program

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also, you can create block-formatted code snippets by indenting a block of text with 4 spaces. Much better than taking screen-shots of the console. You're already doing this in your question.

Comment: The equations look right. So if there's a problem, it's elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Post the definition of `PI` to rule out trivial issues concerning that.

Comment: Hmmm.   In `sin(theta) * (px-ox) + cos(theta) * (py-oy) + oy`, is code using the original `px` or the one updated form the previous line of code?  `p'x` itself is not valid standard C, so that part is unclear.

Comment: You really need to show more code. Are your coordinates integers? And if so, do you round them? If that's the case, your updated variables will still be the same as before if you rotate by 5°, but will change by 1 if you rotate by 6°. Use `double` for your position throughout and round only when you display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't show your code, but I guess that your code looks like this:

```
int x = 5;
int y = 5;
double a = 6 * PI / 180;
int i;

for (i = 0; i < 72; i++) {
    int xx = round(x);
    int yy = round(y);

    putpixel(xx, yy, '*');

    x = round(xx * cos(a) - yy * sin(a));
    y = round(xx * sin(a) + yy * cos(a));
}
```

The variables could also be `double`, but the important thing here is that you round an thereby, depending on your radius and angle, cancel the distance you have covered by rotating. I can reproduce the screenshots you show with the code above.

The solution is to keep the fractional floating-point values throughout and to convert to integer only for printing:

```
double x = 5.0;                 // unrounded actual coordinates
double y = 5.0;
double a = 5 * PI / 180;
int i;

for (i = 0; i < 72; i++) {
    int ix = rint(x);           // temporary integers for plotting
    int iy = rint(y);
    double nx, ny;              // temporary variables for update

    putpixel(x, y, '*');

    nx = x * cos(a) - y * sin(a);
    ny = x * sin(a) + y * cos(a);

    x = nx;
    y = ny;
}
```

This gives a nice, round circle. If you want to draw a pixel circle with integer coordinates, have a look at the [Midpoint algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm).

Comment: The midpoint algorithm is just what I searched for, thank you!